# Relaxation Times in Quantum Optics

Tags: laser

I am studying laser physics and in in the lecture we defined the transversal and longitudinal relaxation times as the relaxation times of the coherent/ population states of the density matrix. The longitudinal relaxation times I understand but what physical meaning do the transversal relaxation times have?

I'd just like to grasp the physical meaning of all of this.